# How to match "{" using regex in c++

Tags: c++, regex

May we have similar question here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348510/how-to-match-using-regex):

But my question is:

First I tried to match all `x` in the string so I write the following code, and it's working well:

```
string str = line;
regex rx("x");
vector<int> index_matches; // results saved here 
        
for (auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), rx);
            it != std::sregex_iterator();
            ++it)
{
  index_matches.push_back(it->position());
}
```

Now if I tried to match all `{` I tried to replace
`regex rx("x");` with `regex rx("{");` and`regex rx("\{");`.

So I got an exception and I think it should throw an exception because we use `{`
sometimes to express the regular expression, and it expect to have `}` in the `regex` at the end that's why it throw an exception.

So first is my explanation correct?

Second question I need to match all `{` using the same code above, is that possible to change the `regex rx("{");` to something else?

Comment: You need to escape characters with special meaning. Please see [the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/).

Comment: regex rx("\{"); will throw an exception as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape characters with special meaning in regular expressions, i.e. use `\{` regular expression. But, `\` has special meaning in C++ string literals. So, next you need to escape characters with special meaning in C++ string literals, i.e. write:

```
regex rx("\\{");
```