# How to match the whole word only with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How exactly do Regular Expression word boundaries work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531724/how-exactly-do-regular-expression-word-boundaries-work-in-php)

How can I match the whole word only with `preg_replace()`?

```
$string = 'C:\wamp\www\global_tolerance_2012\global\models'


$new_string = str_replace('\\', '/',preg_replace('#(.*?)(global).*#', '$1', $string));
```

result,

```
C:/wamp/www/
```

the result I want,

```
C:/wamp/www/global_tolerance_2012/
```

Comment: What changes within the url or are you expecting `global` always? Id perhaps do it like `str_replace('\\','/',stristr($string,'global\\',true));`

Comment: yes it is always `global` or `local`. thanks.

Comment: You need to give the regex a further hint on only matching complete words, or other surrounding characters that can be used as markers. Right now it does what you asked it to do. It can't guess intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = 'C:\wamp\www\global_tolerance_2012\global\models';
$new_string = str_replace( '\\', '/', $string );
$new_string = preg_replace('#/(local|global)/.*#si', '/', $new_string);
```

Comment: thanks but it doesnt work I'm afraid...

Comment: Try now - I just saw your mention of global/local in the comments.