# regex to match word boundary beginning with special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I have regex that matches words fine except if they contain a special character such as 
~Query which is the name of a member of a C++ class.
Need to use word boundary as shown below for member names that are single characters.
`$key =~ /\b$match\b/`

I tried numerous expressions I thought would work such as `/[~]*\b$match\b/` or `/\b[~]*$match\b/`

Is it possible to put a word boundary on words that may contain a special character?

Comment: Can you post exactly what you want to match.. Regex are generated for specific cases, not just by assuming what your string is..

Comment: `/~\b$match\b/` should match `~Query`, assuming that the regex contained in `$match` would match `Query`.  (I just tested, and `" ~foo " =~ /~\bfoo\b/` evaluates as true.)

Comment: $match variable might contain ~Query, Query, or single letter such as p. Are possibly any other strange name developers use for their class methods. Regex is part of a subroutine that is doing a search. All works fine except when $match contains ~Query.

Answer (score 18):

```
\b
```

is short for

```
(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

If you want to treat `~` as a word character, change `\w` to `[\w~]`.

```
(?:(?<![\w~])(?=[\w~])|(?<=[\w~])(?![\w~]))
```

Example usage:

```
my $word_char = qr/[\w~]/;
my $boundary  = qr/(?<!$word_char)(?=$word_char)
                  |(?<=$word_char)(?!$word_char)/x;

$key =~ /$boundary$match$boundary/
```

If we know `$match` can only match something that starts and ends with a `$word_char`, we can simplify as follows:

```
my $word_char   = qr/[\w~]/;
my $start_bound = qr/(?<!$word_char)/;
my $end_bound   = qr/(?!$word_char)/;

$key =~ /$start_bound$match$end_bound/
```

This is simple enough that we can inline.

```
$key =~ /(?<![\w~])$match(?![\w~])/
```

Comment: Thanks this does what I want although it is lengthy.  $key =~ /(?:(?<=[\w~])(?![\w~])|(?<![\w~])(?=[\w~]))$match(?:(?<=[\w~])(?![\w~])|(?<![\w~])(?=[\w~]))/)

Comment: If I need to include other special characters would they be added like this [\w~`]

Comment: The same \b expansion worked for C#, and replacing \w also worked like a charm.

Comment: Is there a work around for Firefox not supporting the look behinds?

Comment: @ikegami, sorry, yes - JavaScript. I'm extracting multiple programming language names (C#, C++) from text. Your code ported over to JS works awesome except for browsers that don't support look behinds :(

Comment: @adam0101, You could use something like `(?:^|[^\w~])([\w~]+)(?![\w~])` and extract the first capture. But you're no longer matching the boundary itself, so it has limitations (e.g. it's harder to use in larger patterns).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't need to check the contents of `$match` (i.e. it always contains a valid identifier) you can write this

```
$key =~ /(?<![~\w])$match(?![~\w])/
```

which simply checks that the string in `$match` isn't preceded or followed by alphanumerics,  underscores or tildes