# Regex not matching hash character between word boundary

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a strange behaviour with the regex `\bC#?\b`

```
string s1 = Regex.Replace("Bla Ca bla", @"\bCa?\b", "[$0]"); // Bla [Ca] bla (as expected)
string s2 = Regex.Replace("Bla C# bla", @"\bC#?\b", "[$0]"); // Bla [C]# bla (why???)
```

Does anyone understand why it happens and how to match an optional `#` at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `\b` is marking the boundaries of the word. And in regexes word is considered a sequence of alphanumeric symbols (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter)), other characters not included. In first example `a` is a letter, so `Ca` is a word. In second `#` is not an alphanumeric character, thus word consists of only `C`.

To see the difference, try removing `\b`:

```
string s2 = Regex.Replace("Bla C# bla", @"C#?", "[$0]"); // Bla [C#] bla
```

If you need `\b` kind of boundary - check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712754/regex-to-match-word-boundary-beginning-with-special-characters) with some suggestions.