# String not matching correct string in alternators using findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

I used re.findall to tokenize strings that not always have to be splitting after a word (a token can have compound words). I got the tokens in the described way. However, it is not keeping dots included in the regex pattern.

For instance, consider the following code:

```
import re
all_domain=['com edu','.com edu','inc.', '.com', 'inc', 'com', '.edu', 'edu']
all_domain.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
domain_alternators = '|'.join(all_domain)

print(domain_alternators)
regex = re.compile(r'\b({}|[a-z-A-Z]+)\b'.format(domain_alternators))
print(regex)
#re.compile('\\b(.com edu|com edu|inc.|.com|.edu|inc|com|edu|[a-z-A-Z]+)\\b')

name= 'BASIC SCHOOL DISTRICT .COM'
result=regex.findall(name.lower())
```

it should return as a result `['basic', 'school', 'district', '.com']` because `.com` has higher priority in the alternators (.com comes before com in the alternator lists):

```
.com edu|com edu|inc.|.com|.edu|inc|com|edu
```

How can I get `['basic', 'school', 'district', '.com']` instead of getting `['basic', 'school', 'district', 'com']`

Thanks

Comment: When you have a string like `.com` there is no `\b` before the `.`. From the docs: `\b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- Escape the alternatives so that `.` could match a dot (that is, use `'|'.join(map(re.escape,all_domain))`)
- Use unambiguous word boundaries, left-hand `(?<!\w)` and right-hand `(?!\w)`, because `\b` meaning is context-dependent, see  [Regular Expression Word Boundary and Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241692) and [regex to match word boundary beginning with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712754) and there are a lot more such questions.

Use

```
import re
all_domain=['com edu','.com edu','inc.', '.com', 'inc', 'com', '.edu', 'edu']
all_domain.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
domain_alternators = '|'.join(map(re.escape,all_domain)) # <-- HERE
regex = re.compile(r'(?<!\w)({}|[a-z-A-Z]+)(?!\w)'.format(domain_alternators))  # <-- HERE

name= 'BASIC SCHOOL DISTRICT .COM'
result=regex.findall(name.lower())
print(result) # => ['basic', 'school', 'district', '.com']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PXCC8d)