# Why does regex word boundy not work for this string?

Tags: regex

String:

```
this is something that should work (bs) sdf
```

RegEx

```
\b\(bs\)\b
```

Shows no matches found. Why?

Here it is on Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/jX2Hy6O0XG

Comment: And a usual hint: if you need to match the `(bs)` when not enclosed with word chars, use `(?<!\w)\(bs\)(?!\w)`.

Comment: can you please let me know what the significance of  `<!` is in your expression?

Comment: A negative lookbehind. Fails the match if its pattern is matched immediately to the left of the current position.

Comment: Please re-close as duplicate of [How exactly do Regular Expression word boundaries work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531724/how-exactly-do-regular-expression-word-boundaries-work-in-php).

Comment: Shall we close every question on SO about word boundary's. There are literally 10,000 +. Each one is different. But it is a complex subject, like this questions variation.

Comment: @sln Every question that has this very wording and same type of chars near `\b`. They all have one and the same root cause: OP does not understand what a word boundary matches in regex. Thus, the close reason is a post explaining the identical situation (there, `\b` is used before `@`, a non-word char, same as `(`).

Comment: Close them all or don't close any, can't have it both ways. Hey, thanks for the regex lesson ...

Comment: Not sure what your talking about, but you bring up points not me.

Comment: What do you mean about points? My answer is a Wiki answer, not giving me any points.

Comment: You know, the comment you deleted saying open it to just get 25 points.

Comment: If I told you how trivial and easy the c code is to determine boundary's you wouldn't believe it. Yet, least understood...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason there is no match is as follows.

A word boundary is defined as

```
 (?:                           # Cluster start
      (?:                           # -------
           ^                             # Beginning of string anchor
        |                              # or,
           (?<= [^a-zA-Z0-9_] )          # Lookbehind assertion for a char that is NOT a word
      )                             # -------
      (?= [a-zA-Z0-9_] )            # Lookahead assertion for a char that is IS a word

   |                              # or,

      (?<= [a-zA-Z0-9_] )           # Lookbehind assertion for a char that is IS a word
      (?:                           # -------
           $                             # End of string anchor
        |                              # or,
           (?= [^a-zA-Z0-9_] )           # Lookahead assertion for a char that is NOT a word
      )                             # -------
 )                             # Cluster end
```

So what does `\b\(` match ?

If `(` is not a word, then `\b` expects a *word* to the left

ie. `(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9_])(`.  But what comes before it is a space,
therefore, no match.

The same with `)\b`  ie `)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_])` but again, what comes after is a space.

If you would like a whitespace boundary, you'd use

`(?<!\S)(..)(?!\S)` which insures whitespace or bos/eos positions before and after.

or, if you need to insure *no word boundary* use the negative word boundary

`\B(..)\B`

Comment: Not everything is a dupe

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is not match is because there is no word boundary between a space and `(` and `)` and a space.

See [what word boundary matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

If you need to match the `(bs)` when not enclosed with word chars, use

```
(?<!\w)\(bs\)(?!\w)
```

See a [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/p8aUdihe5i).

**Details**

- `(?<!\w)` - a negative lookbehind that matches the location in a string that is not preceded with a word char
- `\(bs\)` - a literal `(bs)` string
- `(?!\w)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location that is not immediately followed with a word char.